# Quantifying uncertainty of predictions for new data in the regression tree

Tags: regression, machine-learning, prediction, cart, uncertainty

I used Regression Learner to train my data. I held out 25% of the input for validation and ran different models for training. Based on the results using RMSE and R-squared, I decided to go for the regression tree and export the trained model to make predictions of new data.

Although it is possible to use the trained model to predict responses for new observations, the prediction generates a single value for each new observation. I would like to know how it is possible to calculate the uncertainties of predictions for new data. Or, what is the uncertainty of each leaf node?